# How to use laravel spatie (google analytics) on localhost

Tags: laravel, google-analytics, analytics

I have use laravel spatie (google analytics) on localhost for testing without real domain address.
In config file on this laravel package "analytics-view-id" should to add.
How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To test `spatie/laravel-analytics` you can use any of your personal Analytics domains.

If you do not own one, you will be disappointed.

Comment: My Disappointment Is Immeasurable And My Day Is Ruined, but thanks anyway. You just saved me a lot of time on this.